lmer - How to interpret correlation between Random Factors?
My model:
DV ~ 1 + Time * IV + (1 + Time | Subject_ID)

Where IV is the between-subjects independent variable, and Time is the within-subject repeated measures. DV is the dependent variable. The model does not have a convergence warning/issue.
Here is the Random Effect table:
Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 Subject_ID (Intercept) 1541413  1241.5        
            Time        322490   567.9   -0.75
 Residual               3172063  1781.0 

Q1. What does a "strong" correlation (i.e., > .7) mean, and how should I interpret it in the context of my analysis?
Q2. If the correlation is "strong" or even 1, should I drop the random slope by Time, and only keep the random intercept for Subject_ID?
Q3. If the correlation is "weak" (i.e., <.3), what does that mean and how should I interpret it in the context of my analysis?

The strong negative correlation of the random intercept and slope means that, on average, subjects with a higher intercept have a lower slope, and vice versa.
This may be an actual feature of the process you're studying and is no reason to remove something from your model. However, in the extreme case where it is $1$ or $-1$, this is likely an issue with the estimation.
If the correlation is weak or zero, the interpretation of the random intercept and slope are separate: Everyone has their own starting point and goes in a different direction, and those two are only weakly related, or not at all.

@Roland That is a common misconception. The correlation of fixed effects does not have an intuitive interpretation and it has even been suggested to remove it from the output.
